# VB.NET How do I check if two textboxes are matching two items in a row in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

What I've been trying to do is have a datagridview of logins to my program, and when I try to login I want to check if the username textbox and the password textbox content is the same as two items in the row of the grid.

attempts...

```
 Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    If UsernameTextBox.Text = Form1.DataGridView1 //HERE IS WHERE I GET LOST) and PasswordTextBox.text = form // again Then

        MessageBox.Show("Successfully logged in!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)

        Form1.Show()
        Hide()

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid user credentials", "Failed to login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If





End Sub
```

I really would like help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your database bound to anything like a BindingSource by any chance?

Comment: Nope, I dont think so

Comment: I don't want to sound brash, but do you think so or do you know so? The underlying question to my original question is how is your data being populated in the DataGridView?

Comment: I haven't done anything having to do with "BindingSource" as I don't know what it is.

Comment: So then... how is your data being populated in the DataGridView?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, I have my datagridview and to add users and passwords I have two textboxes which I then have a button to add them into the grid in two different columns in a row. Then when in the grid I want the two items in the row to be able to be used as a login.

I probably didnt get the question correctly because I'm stupid.

Comment: I'm sorry, have you worked with DataGridView Control before?

Comment: No and that is why I am so confused aswell as me being a total noob in general

Comment: This sounds like your password is stored in plaintext in this database.. Worrying!

Comment: its not a serious project and is not to be shared

Comment: @Krizzo the problem youre facing is that you've rocked up here with this question, and we know very little about you so we have to make some assumptions - you start out by saying you have a DataGridView with stuff in it, so we assume you knew how it got there.. The more questions we ask, the more it turns out that you might not even be sure how it got there, which naturally starts to present some issues. Best to be upfront with such scenarios; if someone else wrote the code, and you don't understand a word of it it's better a) give the code and b) say it isn't yours and is a mystery to you

Comment: In most properly written programs the data you see "in a datagridview" *isn't actually in the datagridview* - that's a very VB6 way of looking at the world. The data is probably/should be in something else, perhaps a (strongly typed) datatable, and that is what should be queried. Actually, , going back another step the datatable was filled from a database, and really, actually, it is the *database* that should be queried. Downloading all the users with their plaintext passwords etc isn't wise, not just for the security considerations, but because downloading all of a db table and searching it

Comment: in the client, isn't wise/isn't how these things are supposed to work. Amazon certainly doesn't download all the millions of orders into their web server when I say I want to retrieve my order #12345678

Comment: im gonna go with c) its my code because it is

Comment: Oh, so it's your code but you can't explain how it works, or how the datagridview comes to be showing the data it does? This story just gets stranger

Comment: I just dont understand datagridviews, im sorry

Comment: ignore this thread overall, im sorry

Comment: @Krizzo we would love to help you, but we just need to know how the data is populating the DataGridView. This will in all likelihood tell us how we will answer the question.

Comment: You need to post more code, at a minimum show how the datagridview is populated, but I would like to understand your purpose. Probably there is a better way. If you want to validate login credentials this is not the way to do it. What you need is as simple SELECT query. I can't figure out what you're trying to do.